# Grunt: mongoimport task not found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mongoimport

I am trying to use mongoimport package to import data to my mongodb. I installed mongoimport package as per [mongoimport's npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-mongoimport).
It added following to my package.json:

```
"grunt-mongoimport": "^0.1.3"
```

My Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mongoimport');
grunt.initConfig({
//....some default init tasks
mongoimport: {
  options: {
    db : 'fullstack-dev',
    collections : [
    {
      name : 'submitters',
      type : 'json',
      file : 'lib/config/seedData.json',
    }
    ]
  }
},
//...some more tasks after mongo import
}
```

And then I added this custom task to Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.registerTask('dev:prepare', ['serve:init', 'mongoimport']);
```

And I run the following command:

```
grunt dev:prepare
```

The **serve:init** executes properly but when running **mongoimport**, I get:

```
Running "mongoimport" task
>> Error: not found: mongoimport
```

I am not getting what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Are you on Windows? You need to add mongodb/bin to your system PATH variable.

## Add MongoDB to Windows PATH

1. Open a console window
2. Enter:

   ```
   set PATH=%PATH%;C:\_PATH_\_TO_\_MONGODB_\bin
   ```
3. Log out and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

**Is mongodb installed ?**

This npm module that you are referencing is merely a helper that will help you make a `mongoimport` query with grunt. Can you actually call `mongoimport` from the same console you're calling your grunt tasks from ?